# Varying charge density in cylinder

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Say I have cylinder with a charge density which only varies along the z axis.
Would I be right to say then that a disk cut from this cylinder pretty much has a uniform charge density?

And so if I wanted to get the surface charge density of that disk would it be the surface charge density at that point by dz? I’m struggling to wrap my head around this fully.

Comment: "A charge density which varies only along the z-axis" is hard to interpret.  Do we know nothing about the charge density at points not on the z-axis? Or do you mean "a charge density that varies only in the z direction?

Comment: Yes sorry the charge density only varies along the z direction, meaning it doesn’t vary radially or anything else

Comment: I think, then, that the question in your first paragraph almost answers itself. There is no catch that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've clarified your meaning, I think that the question in your first paragraph almost answers itself, the answer being 'Yes'. There is no catch that I can think of.

As for surface charge density, $\sigma$, this cannot, I believe, be calculated from the volume charge density, $\rho$. For each thin disc (that is for each narrow band of $z$ values) you could, I suppose, define a *surface layer* to have a certain chosen thickness, $\Delta r$, calculate the charge in that layer from the volume density of charge, then divide by the surface area, but the  result ($\sigma=\rho \Delta r$) wouldn't have much significance (owing to the arbitrariness of $\Delta r$). Usually surface charge density is treated as a quantity independent of volume charge density.

Answer (score 0):

If you say cylinder "with a charge density which only varies along the z axis", it means that since the cylinder is a three dimensional object and the charge density is solely a function of z, the charge is only present on along the z axis, so if you take a disk cut at $z=z_0$, then the only charge present on the disk is a single point charge $q$ present at the point $z=z_0$, mathematically, this can be given by using Dirac delta function as $q=\delta (z- z_0) \rho (z)$ , where $\rho (z)$ is the given charge density of the cylinder.

Here the Dirac delta function is present just to indicate that all the charge is distribute at a single point $z=z_0$ and is NOT uniformly distributed.

Comment: Does this apply if I rephrase to “the charge density varies in the z direction” rather than the z axis specifically

Comment: Yes, it does apply then also, as  “the charge density varies in the z direction”  still means "the charge density is solely a function of z"

Comment: But to say that the charge density is solely a function of $z$ means that it is the same at all points in the cylinder with the same $z$ co-ordinate. There is nothing special about points on the $z$ axis.